# Displaying list of all items with the same lookup fields in Display Form of that Lookup field in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, client-side-scripting

I have 2 lists which are **Room** and **Equipment**.

In the **Equipment** list there is a lookup Field to the **Room** list  .

I want to display all related Equipment in **Room** simple tabular Display Form.

How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general solution would be as follow

1. Check you can work with the REST API in JavaScript like below. (in this step you can just make sure the URL is returning XML data you requested)

   ```
   http://portal/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Equipments')/items/?$select=Title,ID&$filter=Room eq 'room1'
   ```
2. create a new custom DisplayForm with SharePoint Designer and add the following jQuery Script to read and generate the previous fetched data at the end of

   ```
   <script src="/_layouts/15/CDN/Js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" >  </script>

   <script type="text/javascript" >

   function LoadEquipments(roomValue) {
       $.ajax({
           url : _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Equipments')/items/" +
           "?$select=Title,ID" +
           "&$filter=Room eq '" + roomValue + "'",

           type : "GET",
           headers : {
               "accept" : "application/json;odata=verbose",
           },
           success : function (data) {

               var equipments = [];
               var results = data.d.results;
               for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {

                   if (equipments.indexOf(results[i].Title) < 0)
                       equipments.push(results[i].Title);
               }

               var ullist = $('<ul/>');

               for (var i = 0; i < equipments.length; i++)
                   $('<li/>').val(equipments[i]).html(equipments[i]).appendTo(ullist);

               ullist.appendTo('#divEquipements'); 
               $("#divEquipements ul li").css("font-size", "16px").css("color", "salmon");

           },
           error : function (err) {
               alert(JSON.stringify(err));
           }
       });
   }

   $(document).ready(function () { 
       var roomVal = $("#TitleValue").text(); 
       LoadEquipments(roomVal); 
   });
   ```
3. for previous code to work as you might guess you would better add id for new td to enclose the new requirements(for example a new tr as the last row which contains aa div with id='divEquipements' ) data and also just add id='TitleValue' to the td containing the room  title (usually the first row)

Answer (score 0):

OK there are a lot of possibilities for achieving this. Some possible and good looking solution can be:

1. Overload the click of the market value in the list(can be done using JSLink) to open a Modal dialog page where all the equipments are listed(fetched using REST query)
2. Overload the click of the market value in the list(can be done using JSLink) and redirect to the same page but with filters to the same view.
3. If the number of markets are not many, views can also be created per market(Not so good, but will reduce coding effort)

If its something else you are looking for, please let know. Hope this helps!

Comment: Many thanx @sahiloona. I think the first solution would be the best. that would be great if you could make more hints or name the steps that i should follow. I am a beginner :(

Comment: For 1: 
Example of jslink: [JSlink](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/524962/JSLink-Custom-JS-Rendering-in-SharePoint-2013)
With the help of above Link add link to a dialog popup which can be an aspx page.
In aspx file on document.ready() method get all items of that market using REST query. For REST refer to link below:
[REST Example](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/124846/rest-with-filter-for-list-items-in-sharepoint-2013)